# How to get the selected value from a kendo dropdownlist within a kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with batch editing enabled which contains a dropdownlist. I can read the other field of the grid while trying to save batch information but getting hard time to read the selected value of the dropdownlist. Here is my code for the grid:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: datasource,
                navigatable: true,
                pageable: true,
                height: 430,
                sortable: true,
                editable: true,
                selectable: "multiple row",
                groupable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                filterable: true,
                toolbar: ["create", "cancel"],
                columns: [

                    { field: "EmployeeID", title: "Employee ID", width: 110 },
                    { field: "EmployeeName", title: "Employee Name", width: 110 },
                    { field: "Category", title: "Category", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, width: 50 },

                    { command: "destroy", title: "Delete", width: 90 }
                ],



            });
        });
```

Here is the code for the dropdownlist:

```
 function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" id="test"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "EmployeeName",
                    dataValueField: "EmployeeID",
                    optionLabel: "Select",
                    autoBind: false,

                    //index: 0,
                    //change: onChange,
                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource( {

                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "/Home/Category",
                                type: "GET"
                            },
                            schema:{
                                model: {
                                    ID: "CategoryID",
                                    Value: "CategoryName"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                });
        }
```

Here is the code where I'm trying to save the values:

```
function Save() {


        var EmployeeInfo = { "EmployeeID": "", "EmployeeName": "", "CategoryID": "" };

        var CompanyInfo = { "CompanyID": "", "CompanyName": "", "Employee": [] };

        CompanyInfo.CompanyID = $("#CompanyID").val();
        CompanyInfo.CompanyName = $("#CompanyName").val();

        var drop = $("#test").data("kendoDropDownList");

        var GridData = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        var data = GridData.dataSource.data();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var item = data[i]; //Got the dropdown selected value & text here, just need to assign that value to the CategoryID attribute!
            EmployeeInfo.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
            EmployeeInfo.EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName; 
            EmployeeInfo.CategoryID = item.CategoryID[0];  //Problem is here in assinging data!!
            CompanyInfo.Employee.push(EmployeeInfo);
            EmployeeInfo = { "EmployeeID": "", "EmployeeName": "" };


        }


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Create',
            data: JSON.stringify(CompanyInfo),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json'

        });
    };
```

How can I get the selected value of the dropdownlist? Another problem is that, after selecting an item in the dropdown, when I'm moving to another line of grid, the selected text getting changed in the dropdown, showing [object, object] instead. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I got the solution of the first problem. It's mapping according to the column name of the grid. So I need to put it like below:  EmployeeInfo.CategoryID=item.Category.CategoryID;

Comment: Now I need the solution of the second problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the DropDownList from `Save` function when very likely that `input` no longer exist. You should simply access that field the same way you access the others. An `editor` function updates the fields because it is an *observable* object.

Try doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    EmployeeInfo.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
    EmployeeInfo.EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName; 
    EmployeeInfo.CategoryID = item.Category,
    CompanyInfo.Employee.push(EmployeeInfo);
    EmployeeInfo = { "EmployeeID": "", "EmployeeName": "" };
}
```

By the way, I'm not sure about the processing that you want to do before sending the data to the server but typically people use `create`, `update` and `destroy` in `DataSource.transport`. It uses to simplify your development and saves you from doing `ajax` calls.

Comment: I got the solution of this problem, can you please help me with the second one I mentioned at the end of my question? Here I'm writing the problem again fyi. after selecting an item in the dropdown, when I'm moving to another line of grid, the selected text getting changed in the dropdown, showing [object, object] instead.

Comment: Yes, I'll use the transport attribute of the grid, I was just experimenting the drop down with in the grid. so I skipped that part for now. anyway thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Paying more attention to your code I see that in `editor` function when you define the `input` field you define `dataTextField` twice. First as `CategoryName` and then as `EmployeeName`. I don't think that is causing the `[object, object]` but you should fix it anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the `[object, object]` but it works fine on my side. Could you tell me the exact steps for getting it? What is your Grid DataSource sending as Category, the name or the id of the category?

Comment: well I was sending the id & name both as json!

Comment: I tried to send only name but in that case list of value showing undefined for every item in the list!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value by passing tag name using jquery.
try this

```
$('#grid select option:selected').val(); // for val


$('#grid select option:selected').text(); // for text
```

Comment: sorry, its not working. It's still not getting the value from the dropdownlist.

Comment: I'm getting the selected value & text both in item, Now I just need to assign the value to the categoryid field! I don't know why its not happening?!

Comment: I got the solution of the first problem. It's mapping according to the column name of the grid. So I need to put it like below: EmployeeInfo.CategoryID=item.Category.CategoryID;

Answer (score 0):

when select a value from a dropdown list, and in the selec event , we can get the selected value as following ,

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("booksDropDown")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:37%" })
              .DataTextField("BookName")
              .DataValueField("BookId")
              .Events(x => x.Select("onSelectBookValue"))
              .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Read(action => action.Action("ReadBookDropDow", "PlanningBook").Type(HttpVerbs.Get)))
              .OptionLabel("Select"))
```

javascript function like following ,

```
      function onSelectBookValue(e) {    

                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                    var bookId = dataItem.BookId;
//other user code
    }
```

I believe this will help someone

Thanks